# How to get the green check for Emails in Explorer using a Button on a ribbon?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I want to check the selected Email in Outlook using a button in a custom ribbon.

I added my ribbon in which a button is placed. If i press the button, the selected Email, should be checked like an emails is marked as task and i click again on the red flag. so there is a green check on this email.

How can I do this by using my button on my custom ribbon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following MAPI properties are set when a message is completed and a green checkbox is displayed (you can see that in Outlook Spy - click IMessage, go to the Watch tab)

```
0x8024000B (TaskComplete)   true
0x80250003 (TaskStatus) 2
0x80C40005 (PercentComplete)    1
PR_FLAG_STATUS  1
PR_REPLY_REQUESTED  false
PR_RESPONSE_REQUESTED   false
```